# find NaN in creating new column based on iteration

Tags: python, pandas

i dont know why i find NaN when i create a new column,
here the code i use for

```
df_new['age'] = df_new['age'].astype('Int64')
usia = []
for i in df_new['age']:
if i < 17:
     usia.append('under_age')
if i >= 17 and i < 31:
    usia.append('dewasa_awal')
if i >= 31 and i < 46:
    usia.append('dewasa_akhir')
if i >= 46 and i < 60 :
    usia.append('lansia_awal')
if i >= 60 and i < 75 :
    usia.append('lansia')
if i >= 75:
    usia.append('lansia_akhir')
column = ['kel_usia']
age = pd.DataFrame(usia, columns=column)
df_new = pd.concat([df_new, age], axis=1).reindex(df_new.index)
```

the result shown below

```
1        dewasa_akhir
4        dewasa_akhir
5         dewasa_awal
6         lansia_awal
7         lansia_awal
    ...     

32948             NaN
32949             NaN
```

Thank in advance

Comment: Try: `df_new['age'].map(type).unique()` and post the result here pls.

Comment: ther results is :     array([<class 'int'>], dtype=object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need to do these lines:

```
age = pd.DataFrame(usia, columns=column)
df_new = pd.concat([df_new, age], axis=1).reindex(df_new.index)
```

because first line makes a new frame with index `0..N-1`; but then the `concat` in second line results in a union of indices i.e., that of `df_new` (which are different than `0..N-1`) and `0..N-1`, and `NaN`s appear. Then you also `reindex` with `df_new`'s index but because of the mentioned difference in indexes, you have `NaN`s still...

So, a fix is to directly assign a column to `df_new` without above 2 lines. This won't change the `df_new`'s indices at all and add a new column filled with `usia`'s values:

```
df_new["kel_usia"] = usia
```

---

(by the way, your `if-elif-else`'s can also be replaced with something like `np.select` or `pd.cut` but that's not the main focus of the question I believe...)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this error with `NaN` and simplify your code, you can use `pd.cut`:

Input data:

```
>>> df_new
   age
0   93
1   26
2   16
3   34
4   58
5   76
6   68
7   14
8   77
9   84
```

```
df_new['kel_usia'] = pd.cut(df['age'], bins=[-1, 17, 31, 46, 60, 75, 9999],
                            labels=['under_age', 'dewasa_awal', 'dewasa_akhir',
                                    'lansia_awal', 'lansia', 'lansia_akhir'])
```

Output result:

```
   age      kel_usia
0   93  lansia_akhir
1   26   dewasa_awal
2   16     under_age
3   34  dewasa_akhir
4   58   lansia_awal
5   76  lansia_akhir
6   68        lansia
7   14     under_age
8   77  lansia_akhir
9   84  lansia_akhir
```